# React hooks conditional render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a functional react component which uses custom hook **useTimer**.This component receives data from API(via redux store).

```
function RenderRespond(order) {
  if(order === null) return;
  const {
    buyerName,
    offerDuration,
  } = order;
  const {
    seconds,
    minutes,
  } = useTimer(offerDuration);
  return(
    <div>
      {BuyerName}
      {minutes}:{seconds}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I only want to render this component when order is not null.The code throws the error that hooks cannot be conditionally rendered.How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should call `useTimer` before the if statement.

Like so:

```
function RenderRespond(order) {
  const {
    buyerName,
    offerDuration = '', // not sure what the default value will be, but you can change it for your needs
  } = order || {};
  const {
    seconds,
    minutes,
  } = useTimer(offerDuration);

  if(order === null) return null;
  return(
    <div>
      {BuyerName}
      {minutes}:{seconds}
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you look at [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation) the reason why this happens is because `if(order === null) return` will prevent the hook to be called, but it will be expecting it to be called;

## Observations

Maybe you have a typo?

You are destructing `buyerName` but rendering `BuyerName` (with capital B).

Comment: But if order is null, accessing buyerName will throw an error.

Comment: @johnnash I added `order || {}`, now your destructing will work fine. I also added `offerDuration = ''` so it won't be `undefined` when you use it in `useTimer`, but you can change it to what you need. I only added empty string because I don't know what is used in `useTimer`.